# Google Chrome autofilling with blank fields

Tags: google-chrome, autofill

This is a slightly strange one that I've not been able to find anything out about. On OSX 10.11.4 using Google Chrome v 55.0.2883.95 (this is a friends computer) when opening a page to update a product on a site I've built some of the fields are blank.

I've tested it on other computers and in safari on his and the data is there and correct. It's also in the database as it should be Chrome just seems to be removing it.

I've turned autofill off wondering if that was the problem but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas would be great - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve the problem. It was browser based but caused by vue.js working correctly on some browsers but not others.

Disabling the vue aspect of the page sorted it. Now I need to sort Vue :)